# How do I store values into a table along with join query in laravel?

Tags: laravel, join, laravel-5, inner-join

I have three tables:->
-- Student(PK userid)
-- Teacher(PK teacherid, FK userid ref...)
-- Rating(PK rateid, FK userid ref....., FK teacherid ref....)
I want to insert into rating table by joining with other tables. How do I achieve that in Laravel 5.2? Please help me out guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done in Larvel using Polymorphic relationships

To make it simpler, here's a sample db structure:

```
student
    id - integer
    user_id - integer

teacher
    id - integer
    user_id - integer

ratings
    id - integer
    value - integer
    rateable_id - integer
    rateable_type - string
```

The `rateable_id` corresponds to either the `id` on `teacher` or `student`
The `rateable_type` is a string of the class name of the model that is rateable. This is added automatically for you, as explained below.

Your models should look like this:

`Rating.php`

```
class Rating extends Model
{
    public function rateable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

`Teacher.php`

```
class Teacher extends Model
{
    public function rating()
    {
        return $this->morphOne(Rating::class, 'rateable');
    }
}
```

`Student.php`

```
class Student extends Model
{
    public function rating()
    {
        return $this->morphOne(Rating::class, 'rateable');
    }
}
```

Now, here's a small example on how to use this.

```
$student = Student::find(1);

$rating = new Rating();
$rating->value = 10;

$student->rating()->save($rating);
```

First you find a student. Then you create a new rating and add a value.

When you do `$student->rating()->save($rating);` the `rateable_id` and `rateable_type` are filled in for you, with the correct value for your `Student.php` model through the relationship. Simple with Laravel.

Comment: Thanks for replying mate! Thats exactly what I needed. Thanks once again. :-)

Comment: I exactly want to accomplish the same. But I am a bit confused regarding the sample db structure. Could you please explain a bit! Thanks!

Comment: Also I read about polymorphic relationship and I got to know that we can use it in somewhat this scenario: imagine users of your application can "like" both posts and comments.

Comment: And what I need is only students can rate teachers and the rate value will be stored on rating table synchronized with respective teacher and student